# How can we block write function in linux?

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to block write() function in linux in my code.
What can we done to block the write() function in such a way it is blocked and returns -1?

I'm trying to fail write() function, to hit an error to check the code, I've written.

Should I block or unblock I/O to fail the write() function in linux?
write() function that handles file descriptor.

Comment: `int write(...) { return -1; }`?

Comment: What do you mean exactly ? Make the writes impossible ? Why would you want to do that in your own code ?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What is the actual and underlying problem that's supposed to solve? Right now your question is too much of an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: @KamilCuk: the linker might not appreciate.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm trying to fail it, so it can hit an error and check my code in issue state.

Comment: @KamilCuk, this is a linux funxtion. Can't be failed like that

Comment: @SharonDeborah Yes it can. (?) Have you tried it? Works fine.

Comment: So you want to *mock* the `write` function, for unit testing?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes

Comment: @KamilCuk, can we manipulate a system call?

Comment: I do understand the question. Please define "manipulate".

Comment: @YvesDaoust, Someprogrammerdude This is a deep and interesting question.  Suppose you have the straightforward code `if(write(fd, buf, n) < 0) { fprintf(stderr, "write error!"); }`.  Suppose you have a requirement to explicitly test every bit of your program's functionality.  Perhaps you are using formal [code coverage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage) techniques to ensure that your tests exercise every line of code.  But that `fprintf` call will remain untested, unless you can figure out a way to generate, simulate, emulate, or otherwise trigger an actual write failure.

Comment: @SteveSummit: there's nothing deep here. The question might be about overloading the function for testing purposes, but this is not explained at all in the OP. I disagree to "guess" the intent of a question and pretend that I know what it is about, I prefer to ask.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I see that the OP's line *I'm trying to fail write() function, to hit an error to check the code, I've written* was added after you asked your question.  But the intent is adequately clear now, I think.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Why do you think the linker would care? `write` is just a symbol like any other. If it is already defined when the linker is evaluating object modules in a library, the linker will not take an object module from the library because the object module defines `write`.

Comment: @SharonDeborah: `write` is not a system call. It is a library routine that contains a system call internally, using some form of trap or system call instruction. For linking purposes, it is an ordinary routine the same as any other routine, and you can use your own routine in its place. The only issue that would arise is if the object module it is in in the library also defines other symbols, such as `writev`, that your program also uses. Then a reference to `writev` in the program could cause the module to be included by the linker, resulting in multiple definitions of `write`.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: GCC is a compiler collection. Visual Studio is an IDE. Neither is a linker. Both might invoke a linker. The linker used for Linux builds will not care about unneeded symbols defined in a library; by themselves, such symbols will not cause multiple definition errors.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Having a symbol defined in a program’s primary object modules and in a library does not cause a multiply defined symbol. The procedure `ld` uses decides whether to include an object module from a library based on whether or not that module defines any symbols that are, at the current time in the link process, referenced but not defined by the output being built. If a symbol is already defined by the output being built, it will not cause the linker to include the object module from the library.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: And who is using Microsoft’s `link` and not `ld` for building a Linux program? The question is about Linux `write`. It is tagged `linux`.

Answer (score 4):

> What can we done to block the write() function in such a way it is blocked and returns -1?

Options:

- Just write your own `write()` function that returns `-1`.

  ```
  ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t s) { return -1; }
  ```

  A bit of trivia: glibc and musl export *weak* symbols for most C library functions, and your code will be linked first before C standard library. This all makes the linker prefer the function that you provide over C standard library implementation.
- Use `-Wl,--wrap=write` when linking and provide `__wrap_write` implementation.
- `ptrace` the program and modify return value of `write`

Answer (score 3):

If you want `write()` to fail you can write to special file `/dev/full` which simulates "No space left on device":

```c
// write.c

#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void)
{
    static const char data[] = "Hello World!\n";

    ssize_t ret = write(STDOUT_FILENO, data, sizeof(data));

    int err = errno;

    fprintf(stderr, "write() returned %zi\n", ret);

    if (ret == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "errno: %i (%s)\n", err, strerror(err));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Run:

```
$ ./write > /dev/full 
write() returned -1
errno: 28 (No space left on device)
```

Comment: 20 years of linux programming and I did not know that /dev/full existed

Comment: @KamilCuk: though after 20 years, you must know a few per thousand of it... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to check the return value of `write` in code that is under your control, you could call a different function, e.g. `testWrite`, which either calls `write` or returns `-1` when you decide to do so:

```
int testWrite(...) {
   // return write(...);
   return -1;
}
```

or

```
int testWrite(...) {
   if(projectIsInTestMode) {
      return -1;
   } else {
      return write(...);
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Sorry if I didn't make my question clear. But I'm working with write() function in linux that handles file descriptor

Answer (score 0):

I have occasionally induced write errors by running a program with its output going to a file which happens to be on an external USB "thumb drive", and then deliberately unplugging the drive while the program is running.  (The operating system may issue its usual stern warnings about the disk being unmounted improperly, but sometimes we have to make these sacrifices in the name of science. ☺)

Another possibility is to write to a file that's network-mounted on another computer, and disconnect the network cable (or turn off WiFi, etc.) while the program is running.  This tends to cause *very* difficult-to-handle errors, though (especially as things are liable to hang, not error out).

Another possibility is to run your program on a disk that's nearly full, or to deliberately fill up the disk (from another window) while the program is running.